# Issue with looping through json object within jquery.html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file I wat to loop through the items and display it,

My code is:

```
$('.btn-refresh').on('click',function(){
  //start ajax request
  $.ajax({
      url: "April.json",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#resultSet").append("<h3> " + data.currentMonth.toUpperCase() +" 2017</h3>" +
          "<table><tbody><tr><th>DATE</th><th>SUMMARY</th></tr>  " +
          for(date in data.days){
            "<tr><td rowspan='2' class='day_collapse'><a href='#'> "+ data.currentMonth +" </a></td></tr> " +
            "<tr ><td> "+
              "<table class='time_stamp_display'>" +
                "<tbody><tr><th> TIME </th><th> RESULT </th></tr> <tr>" + 
                  "<td> 06:00 am </td> " + 
                  "<td> SUCCESS </td> " + 
                  "</tr>  </tbody></table></td></tr> "+ 
                }
                  "</tbody></table>");
      },
      error: function(xhr){
        console.log("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      }
  });

});
```

April.json

```
{"currentMonth":"April","days":{"7":{"timeOfExecution":"18:15","summaryForTheDay":{"Message":"Successful!!! GPS Location received","latency":106,"isSuccess":true,"18:20":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"18:23":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false}}},"10":{"timeOfExecution":"11:09","summaryForTheDay":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false,"11:20":{"Message":"Successful!!! GPS Location received","latency":103,"isSuccess":true},"11:23":{"Message":"Successful!!! GPS Location received","latency":108,"isSuccess":true},"10:09":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"10:20":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"10:51":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"11:09":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"11:12":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"11:22":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"11:28":{"Message":"Successful!!! GPS Location received","latency":107,"isSuccess":true}}}}}
```

The for loop isn't working,
Suggest a solution to populate data within the html.

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)`

Comment: Remember, JS is not PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You suffer from wishful thinking :)

- You cannot loop in a concatenation.
- You cannot append half a table
- You should not have TH in tbody

Here is the loop you need, creating valid HTML

```js
var data = {"currentMonth":"April","days":{"7":{"timeOfExecution":"18:15","summaryForTheDay":{"Message":"Successful!!! GPS Location received","latency":106,"isSuccess":true,"18:20":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"18:23":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false}}},"10":{"timeOfExecution":"11:09","summaryForTheDay":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false,"11:20":{"Message":"Successful!!! GPS Location received","latency":103,"isSuccess":true},"11:23":{"Message":"Successful!!! GPS Location received","latency":108,"isSuccess":true},"10:09":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"10:20":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"10:51":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"11:09":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"11:12":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"11:22":{"Message":"Failure!!! GPS Location not received","latency":0,"isSuccess":false},"11:28":{"Message":"Successful!!! GPS Location received","latency":107,"isSuccess":true}}}}}


var $res = $("#resultSet").html("");
$res.append("<h3> " + data.currentMonth.toUpperCase() + " 2017</h3>")
var $tab = $("<table><thead><tr><th>DATE</th><th>SUMMARY</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody>");
var $tbod = $("tbody",$tab);
for (date in data.days) {
  $tbod.append("<tr><td rowspan='2' class='day_collapse'><a href='#'> " + data.currentMonth + " </a></td></tr> " +
    "<tr ><td> " +
    "<table class='time_stamp_display'>" +
    "<thead><tr><th> TIME </th><th> RESULT </th></tr></thead><tbody><tr>" +
    "<td> 06:00 am </td> " +
    "<td> SUCCESS </td> " +
    "</tr></tbody></table></td></tr> ");
}
$res.append($tab);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resultSet"></div>
```

Comment: Now I want to loop through the data.days.summaryForTheDay."18:20" and fetch all the data within it, for all the values, like "18:20", "18:23" etc. How to loop that ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to write your loop outside the append and add than append the value to div.

```
$('.btn-refresh').on('click',function(){
  //start ajax request
  $.ajax({
      url: "april.josn",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {

          var $table = "<h3> " + data.currentMonth.toUpperCase() + " 2017</h3>" +
  "<table><tbody><tr><th>DATE</th><th>SUMMARY</th></tr>";

for (date in data.days) {
  $table+="<tr><td rowspan='2' class='day_collapse'><a href='#'> " + data.currentMonth + " </a></td></tr> " +
    "<tr ><td> " +
    "<table class='time_stamp_display'>" +
    "<tbody><tr><th> TIME </th><th> RESULT </th></tr> <tr>" +
    "<td> 06:00 am </td> " +
    "<td> SUCCESS </td> " +
    "</tr>  </tbody></table></td></tr> ";
}
$table+="</tbody></table>"
console.log($table)

        $("#resultSet").append($table);
      },
      error: function(xhr){
        console.log("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      }
  });

});
```

Comment: Now I want to loop through the data.days.summaryForTheDay."18:20" and fetch all the data within it, for all the values, like "18:20", "18:23" etc. How to loop that ?